# I want to do an animation with my text block... is moving my text from left to right

Tags: c#

I did this below..but the double animation intelliscence ain't showing up...what other way do I move my text in a label or text block to and fro

```
void Window1_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    DoubleAnimation doubleAnimation = new DoubleAnimation();
    doubleAnimation.From = -tbmarquee.ActualWidth;
    doubleAnimation.To = canMain.ActualWidth;
    doubleAnimation.RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever;
    doubleAnimation.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.Parse("0 : 0 : 10"));
    tbmarquee.BeginAnimation(Canvas.LeftProperty, doubleAnimation);
```

Comment: The TimeSpan.Parse part will most likely throw an exception already.

Comment: Wat do I do to ensure DAT d double animation intelliscene shows up?

Comment: @DexDee use `TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)` so you don't need to parse the timespan. (Or remove the spaces to fix the exception: `"0:0:10"`).

Comment: _"the double animation intelliscence [sic] ain't showing up"_ -- what does that even mean? (And no, I'm not talking about the foolish use of the slang "ain't"). What "IntelliSense" did you expect to see but don't? Why did you think the code you posted would cause that? What does IntelliSense have to do with whether the `TextBlock` actually _moves_? Please put more care into your question; take the time to formulate a _useful_, _understandable_ question. See [ask] for advice on how to present your question in a clear, answerable way.